# Flat Rate shipping price is not being applied at OnePageCheckout

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

I have set up flat rate shipping as such:

```
Enabled: Yes
Title: International Shipping
Method Name: International Shipping
Type: Per Order
Price: 14.99
Calculate Handling Fee: Fixed
Handling Fee: 0
Display Error Message: Default
Ship to Applicable Countries: Specific Countries
Ship to Specific Countries: Canada
Show Method if not applicable: Yes
```

However, when i get to the shipping method step, it displays
International Shipping: $0.00

and yes, I am using a proper Canadian address.

I have not modified OnePage.php at all, so it should be grabbing the price I set on the back end, but it is not. Can anyone offer some insight as to whats going on?

UPDATE:

I've discovered that the shipping price will only be applied to customers that are logged in. If you check out as a guest, the shipping price will not be applied. Since there is no way to set user groups for shipping options, there is no way to resolve this as of yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your handling fee is 0.
Change that value, leave the price empty!

Price is only to be mentioned if you have selected "type".

this is how it should look

Enabled: Yes
Title: International Shipping
Method Name: International Shipping
Type: none
Price: 0
Calculate Handling Fee: Fixed
Handling Fee: 14.99

Answer (score 2):

Check your Promotion Rules. Probably there's a rule where shipping method is free.

Comment: Good suggestion, but there are no shopping cart promotion rules for free shipping

Comment: In my case, I had a rule :) I disabled it and now i have shipping cost. Thnx for the suggestion